# Is it possible to get the coefficients of the power series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

If we have a function $f(s)$ with this form:

$$
f(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} p_i s^i
$$

We also know that:

$$
f(1) = 1
$$

and

$$
p_i \ge 0 \quad \text {for all $ i \ge 0$}
$$

Assume we can calculate $f(s)$ for any $s$, is it possible that with all the info we know, we would be able to get $p_n$ for any n?

(Actually $p_i$ is the probability that $[Z=i]$ where Z is a random variable.)

Comment: This is not a polynomial (unless all but finitely many $p_n$'s vanish); the degree of the polynomial has to be finite.

Comment: Coefficients of a *power series*, you mean. If you can evaluate $f$ for any **complex** $s$, then sure...

Comment: Your series will necessarily be the Taylor series of $f(s)$ about $s = 0$. Then ${\displaystyle p_i = {f^{(i)}(0) \over i!}}$ for all $i$, where $f^{(i)}(0)$ denotes the $i$th derivative of $f(s)$ at $s = 0$.

Comment: [In any event...](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64302)

Comment: Could you answer my question? Can you, or can you not, evaluate $f(s)$ for *complex* $s$, or are you restricted to evaluating for real $s$?

Comment: No, I can't, although the problem doesn't indicate the domain of s explicitly, in the context, $s$ is a real number.

Comment: Then either the Richardson or Lanczos methods in the answer I linked to might be of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the discrete version of the [moment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_moments)  or the infinite version of a [Vandermonde matrix.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)  One approach is that $p_0=f(0),\quad p_1=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm df(s)}{\mathrm ds}\right|_{s=0}$ and the higher $p$'s are higher derivatives at $0$.  Of course, this is rather unstable numerically.

Comment: The thing is, according to my understanding of the problem.  What I can get is only $f(s)$, not $f'(s)$.  In fact, I'm trying to construct a random variable with the same distribution as $Z$, but without knowing $p_0, p_1, p_2, \ldots $, it seems impossible .  That's why I'm trying to get all $p_i$'s.

Comment: You can take a numeric derivative.  Take $s$ smaller and smaller and check $\frac{f(s}-f(0)}{s}$.  That is where the instability comes from-you are subtracting two nearly equal quantities.

Comment: @ablmf: you can do [Richardson extrapolation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65569/65619#65619) in conjunction with Ross's "take $s$ smaller and smaller" strategem. It doesn't completely cure the numerical instability, but you might manage to squeeze out a few more digits of accuracy as long as you don't shrink $s$ too much.