# Is there more than one way to express a derivative as a limit of a quotient?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $r(t)$ be a real-valued function of $t$.  Let $v(t)$ be the derivative of $r(t)$.  Then $$v(t) = \frac{dr(t)}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t)}{\Delta t}$$ so $$v(t) = \frac{dr(t)}{dt} \approx \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t)}{\Delta t} \text{ for small }\Delta t$$

My question is, is there another way to approximate $v(t) = \dfrac{dr(t)}{dt}$?

For example, I am reading the book [*Understanding Molecular Simulation* by Frenkel and Smit (Second Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122673514).  On page 71 (some pages are available on Google Books [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=5qTzldS9ROIC&pg=PA71)), the authors write $$v(t) = \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t - \Delta t)}{2 \Delta t} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)$$ or, in other words, $$v(t) \approx \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t - \Delta t)}{2 \Delta t}$$

Basically, then, it seems that there are two ways to express $v(t) = \dfrac{dr(t)}{dt}$:

$$v(t) = \frac{dr(t)}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t)}{\Delta t} \textbf{ (1)}$$

$$v(t) = \frac{dr(t)}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{r(t + \Delta t) - r(t - \Delta t)}{2 \Delta t} \textbf{ (2)}$$

Are equations **(1)** and **(2)** equivalent?  Equation **(1)** Is the definition of derivative that I remember from high school calculus; I do not remember **(2)**.  Is **(2)** an alternative definition of the derivative?  Or, what is the relationship between **(1)** and **(2)**?

Comment: i  can think about one thing,they are same according to following situation,consider difference between  $5$ and $4$  difference is $1$ while difference between $5$ and $3$ is $2$ or $2*1$,i think the same principle is here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to write a modified version of the definition of the derivative that have in fact higher convergence rates and are thus often desirable to use in numerical computation.

[Finite difference coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients) can be used for this.  For example, we have

$$f'(x_0)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+O(h)$$

but

$$f'(x_{0}) \approx \displaystyle \frac{-\frac{11}{6}f(x_{0}) + 3f(x_{+1}) -\frac{3}{2}f(x_{+2}) +\frac{1}{3}f(x_{+3}) }{h_{x}} + O\left(h_{x}^3  \right)$$

**Addendum:** Here is a [giant list](http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2010/09/04/Numerical-differentiation-formulas.aspx) of high-accuracy derivatives using these coefficients.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean that equation **(2)** in the original post is a correct definition of the derivative?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, very much so!  This is a basic three-point estimate.  In fact, this derivative formula is mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Finite_difference_formula - the error seems to be $$\frac{f^{(3)}(c)h^2}{6}$$ where $$c \in [x-h, x+h]$$

Comment: Thanks! So, based on the link you provided, it seems that equation **(2)**, a three-point estimate, is an actually *more* accurate approximation of the derivative than equation **(1)**, a two-point estimate.  Is this true?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it is true.  Instead of having a bias to the side that the limit is taken, this method has a balance.

Comment: @Andrew Your (2) is (6) from this paper: http://www.karenkopecky.net/Teaching/eco613614/Notes_NumericalDifferentiation.pdf

Comment: "...thus often desirable to use in numerical computation." - not always. To borrow a mantra from a certain popular book on numerics, *high order does not necessarily imply high accuracy*. One must remember that the basis of the high-order approximations is the use of an interpolating polynomial at equispaced points, and it is well-known how unruly high-order interpolating polynomials can be...

Answer (score 7):

If the limit (1) exists, the limit (2) exists. To see this, write
$$
\frac{r(t+h)-r(t-h)}{2h}=\frac12\left(\frac{r(t+h)-r(t)}{h}+\frac{r(t+(-h))-r(t)}{(-h)}\right).
$$
The other implication is wrong, otherwise every *even* function would be differentiable at $t=0$ with derivative zero (but $t\mapsto|t|$ is a counterexample).

Hence (2) is not a definition of the derivative.
The definition of the derivative is (1). But as soon as (1) holds, the derivative coincides with the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{r(t+ah)-r(t-bh)}{(a+b)h},
$$
for every $(a,b)$ such that $a+b\ne0$, and in particular with the limit in (2).

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer? Thanks for this view, I hadn't though of it this way

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to other fine answers (did's for example) let's suppose that $f$ admits a Taylor expansion at $t$ then :

$$f(t+h)=f(t)+hf'(t)+\frac {h^2}2 f''(t)+\frac {h^3}6 f'''(t) +O\left(h^4 f''''(t)\right)$$

so that :
 $$\tag{1}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}h=f'(t)+\frac {h}2 f''(t)+\frac {h^2}6 f'''(t) +O\left(h^3 f''''(t)\right)$$
while :
 $$\tag{2}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t-h)}2=f'(t)+\frac {h^2}6 f'''(t) +O\left(h^3 f''''(t)\right)$$

That is why the second method is more precise : the $f''$ term disappeared (well all the even terms in fact!) so that $f'$ will be evaluated with more precision (with an $h^2$ error instead of $h$). Because of the precision obtained Feynman proposed this second method to evaluate derivatives in his famous Physics Lectures (Vol I 9-6).

But when there is no convergence ($f(t)=\frac 1t$ for example) you'll get a limit in the second case ($0$) without any problem and that's clearly different of the first case.

The second method is much used too when you need a 'discretized' version of a differential equation (respecting time symmetry, energy conservation and so on). 
Ed Fredkin for example proposed following equation in his article "Feynman, Barton and the reversible Schrödinger difference equation" :
$$\frac{C_{x,t+1}-C_{x,t-1}}2=ik\left(C_{x-1,t}-2C_{x,t}+C_{x+1,t}\right)$$

Comment: @Raymound:These techniques are used in numerical methods.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: yes you are right (I insisted on the symmetric part of the second method),

Comment: Oh, the central difference is very useful in numerics indeed. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65619).

Comment: Thanks for the link(s) @J.M. !

Answer (score 2):

Consider the linear terms in the Taylor series of $r(t+h)$ and $r(t-h)$, where $h = \Delta t$ and $r'(t)=v(t)$,
$$ r(t+h) \approx r(t) + r'(t)\,h  $$ 
and
$$ r(t-h) \approx r(t) - r'(t)\,h $$
Multiplying the second equation by $-1$ and adding 
$$ 2h r'(t) = r(t+h) + r(t-h) \Rightarrow v(t) \approx  \frac{r(t+h) + r(t-h)}{2h}\,, $$

which implies

$$ v(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{r(t+h) + r(t-h)}{2h} $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another equivalent definition: $f'(x) = \lim_{r \to 1} \frac{f(rx) - f(x)}{(r-1)x}$, if $x \ne 0$. The differentiation rule $\frac{d}{dx}x^n = n x^{n-1}$ is especially easy to derive with this definition.

Comment: Thanks. Are you implying that equation **(2)** in the original post is indeed a correct definition of a derivative?  The answer by did seems to imply it is not.

Comment: @Andrew, it isn't a good definition. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170948).

Comment: @Andrew: When you have questions about some parts of an answer, you might as well ask directly the author.