# Second derivative of class $C^2$ expressed as limit

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^2$. Show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)}{h^2}=g''(a).$$

It seems like an application of mean-value theorem might help: Since $g$ is differentiable, for any $h>0$ there exists $h_1\in(0,h)$ such that $$g(a+h)-g(a)=h\cdot g'(a+h_1).$$ And then since $g'$ is differentiable, there exists $h_2\in(0,h_1)$ such that $$g'(a+h_1)-g'(a)=h_1\cdot g''(a+h_2).$$ Combining the two we have $$g(a+h)-g(a)=hg'(a)+hh_1g''(a+h_2).$$ which doesn't quite get to the desired expression.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: @Adriano Sure. Hmm... seems like using L'Hospital twice yields the result, right?

Comment: Yeah. It should be possible to do it with the limit definition of a derivative though...hmm...

Comment: Here is the [same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210264/second-derivative-formula-derivation/210273#210273).

Comment: [Related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180072/is-there-more-than-one-way-to-express-a-derivative-as-a-limit-of-a-quotient/180118#180118).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is not off, but doesn't seem to work. I would rather consider using Taylor's Theorem.

Namely, we can write $$g(a+h)-g(a)=hg'(a)+\frac 1 2g''(a)h^2+o(h^2)$$ $$g(a-h)-g(a)=-hg'(a)+\frac 1 2g''(a)h^2+o(h^2)$$

Summing gives that your expression is $$g''(a)+\frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}\to g''(a)$$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: If we only know that $g$ is of class $C^2$, can we write down the Taylor series, which includes derivatives of all orders?

Comment: @PJMiller I am not writing a series, but rather writing up to the second order which is indeed valid by Taylor's Theorem.