# Differentiability of function under limit condition.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> For a continuous function $f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$, the following limit exists.
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(-3x)}{x}.$$
> For such a function, is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$?

Idea. I tried to find a counterexample as there is no reason for $f(x)$ to be differentiable.

Also, as a famous example of $f(x)=|x|$ where $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}$ exists but not differentiable, I tried to mimic this example.

But, because of the factor $2$ and $3$, I failed to find a counterexample or prove it.

Comment: Instead of $y = |x|,$ which arises by joining at the origin the $y > 0$ portions of the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = -x,$ use the function that arises by joining at the origin the $y>0$ portions of the graphs of $y = 2x$ and $y = -3x.$

Comment: That example is not we want. That kind of exmaple gives a example where only right derivative or left derivative exists.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That wouldn't be a counterexample, since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(-3x)}{x}$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Varun Vejalla (and OP): Oops, you're right. I was thinking of what is sometimes called the [pseudo-symmetric derivative](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseuso-symmetric+derivative%22), which is different than what we have here where, before the function evaluations, the coefficient of $x$ varies.

Comment: Recall that if $f$ is differentiable at $x=a,$ then the symmetric derivative exists and equals $f'(a).$ (This is a common calculus/real-analysis exercise. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2849316/13130) for example.) Thus, if $f$ is differentiable at $x=0,$ then both $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(-2x)}{x}$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{f(3x)-f(-3x)}{x}$ exist, and you might be able to do something with this.

Answer (score 1):

Such a function will be differentiable at zero ($f(0)=0$ is a red herring, it doesn't contribute to the result). If we set
$$r(x) = \frac{f(2x)-f(-3x)}x$$
and call $\ell$ its limit, then up to considering $x\mapsto f(x)-\frac\ell 5x$ we can assume $\ell=0$.

Fix an $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ such that $|r(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$. Then writing
$$f(x)-f\left(\frac{4x}9\right) = -\big(f(2y)-f(-3y)\big)-\big(f(2z)-f(-3z)\big)$$
with $y=-x/3$ and $z=2x/9$, we see that $|f(x)-f(4x/9)|$ is at most $5\varepsilon|x|/9$. Now
$$f(x)-f(0)
 = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(f(x)-f\left(\frac{4^{k+1}x}{9^{k+1}}\right)\right)
 = \sum_{k\geq 0}\left(f\left(\frac{4^kx}{9^k}\right)-f\left(\frac{4^{k+1}x}{9^{k+1}}\right)\right)$$
by continuity of $f$ at zero, so
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\right|
\leq \frac{5\varepsilon}9\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{4^k}{9^k}
   = \varepsilon $$
on a neighbourhood of zero.

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f'(0)=0$.