# Is the function $f$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus

let $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function having a property as given $$ \lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x-h)\over h}$$ exists for all $x \in \Bbb R$ then $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x \in \Bbb R$. **True/false??**

> I think its true as $$ \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x-h)\over h} ...(1)$$ exists for all $x \in \Bbb R$ so put $x=x+h$ in $(1)$ so  $$ \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+2h)-f(x)\over h}$$ exists i.e  $$ 2\lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+2h)-f(x)\over 2h}$$ exists and taking $k=2h$ then  $$ 2\lim_{k\to 0} {f(x+k)-f(x)\over k}$$ exists i.e $2f^{'}(x)$ exists so $f^{'}(x)$ exists for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
>   **Is this is right??**

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170948/why-use-the-derivative-and-not-the-symmetric-derivative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of $f(x) = \begin{cases}0 \text{ if } x \ne 0\\1 \text{ if } x = 0\end{cases}$.  It obeys your property (easy to prove) but it's not even continuous in $0$.

The point is that with your property you're sampling your function *only* outside of the point where you're computing the limit, therefore the limit value may not match the actual function value at that point.

In you reasoning, replacing $x+h$ by $x$ is illegal, because you're changing a term that is variable in $h$ with a term independent of $h$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x \text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ -x \text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}.$$
Then at $x=0$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h-h}{h}=0.$$
But $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. In the rest of its domain $f$ is trivially smooth.